# Practice for code collabrate with code igniter and git

Tags: git, codeigniter

I am working with few teammates for a codeigniter project using GIT for source control. Problem is when few peoples work on the code, it might create unexpected bugs.

How to prevent this? Test script, tester?

Comment: The question is not clear...can u elaborate what exactly u want ?

Comment: @Girish, basically I am curious about how codeigniter developer collabrate with GIT, as we our updated code might conflict with someone and create bugs. But, there's no complete test suite for codeigniter, so I wondering how do they test the code before they rollout their release.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be interested in test driven development (TDD). This allows your team to create tests for each method/function in your code that can tell if that method/function is executing as expected. There are quite a few resources for doing TDD within codeigniter. Take a look here:

http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=codeigniter+test+driven+development

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to understand how Git works.This will probably solve most of your problems. Refer[Gitref](http://gitref.org/remotes/) . This a good and precise description of how to use git for any projects. These basics apply to all programming languages, frameworks and platforms.

Hope this solves your problems...